# Getting display:flex to behave like display:inline-block

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bigcommerce

I'm having an issue where when my nav items were set to `inline-block`, the sub-menu would render right below the the appropriate `<li>`, like these two examples:

[image]

and

[image]

Now that it is a inline-flex, it is rendering right on top of the li instead, covering it.

I tried manually positioning the submenu `52px` down, but that is only a solution if the `<li>` is on the top row, since once it's on the 2nd row it would now need to be `104px` down.

Is there any good way to fix this?

*URL in comments below*

Comment: Post your code (a minimal working code snippet) if you want a proper answer

Comment: I'm not exactly positive what's the expected final look

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the expected look is the two photos in the original post. This is what is currently happening: http://i.imgur.com/USGI9E9.png

Comment: @LGSon Link to site in question: http://christmascentralsandbox.mybigcommerce.com/

Comment: When external links die, so does the value of this question for future users, so questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although these are default values. Try to set `flex-basis: 0;` also make sure the `flex-wrap: nowrap;` is set. As comment instructed it is wiser to share your code to have a detailed answer.

Edit 1: 
Thank you for the link to the code. Question is now clear, solution can be achieved by giving higher `order` number to the `.navPage-subMenu` class.
But first please remove the `position: absolute` from the class name `.navPage-subMenu` then add the order value of you like higher then `<li>`'s have. Example:

`.navPage-subMenu.is-open {
    order: 111; /*must be higher than <li> order numbers*/
 }`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that didnt seem to work. Here is the site in question: http://christmascentralsandbox.mybigcommerce.com/

Comment: @BrandonD Thank you for the comment and explanation hope this will be clear please let me know if you have any questions. Useful link for the order property of flex items [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)